# How to make a firebase object to only write data not read?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-security

I'm still kinda new to Firebase and in implementing security with Firebase's Security rules.I'm working a project where I need to save data in Firebase but I don't clients to access the data. Basically storing an input field's value. But letting then access it. I'm using AngularFire and when I initialize

```
var ref = new Firebase(url);
$scope.data = $firebaseObject(ref);
```

It fetches all the objects on that reference. I tried changing the security rules

```
{
".read": false,
"write" : true
}
```

But it's throwing error

```
auth_payload = { "uid": "anotherclient", "auth_data": "client" }
```

Answer (score 3):

A `$firebaseObject()` synchronizes data from the Firebase server to your client. So there is no way to use it in a way that is not reading the data.

But if you want to simply write data to Firebase, you can do that easily by using the Firebase JavaScript SDK (which the AngularFire library is built on):

```
ref.set({ 
  title: "How to make a firebase object to only write data not read?",
  url: "http://stackoverflow.com/q/35997606"
})
```

As Kato mentioned in the comments, from [the role of AngularFire](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/intro-to-angularfire.html#section-getting-started):

> It's not always necessary to set up AngularFire bindings to interact with the database. This is particularly true when just writing data, and not synchronizing it locally. Since you already have a Firebase reference handy, it is perfectly acceptable to simply use the vanilla Firebase client library API methods.

Comment: From [The role of AngularFire](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/intro-to-angularfire.html#section-angularfire-intro): It's not always necessary to set up AngularFire bindings to interact with the database. This is particularly true when just writing data, and not synchronizing it locally. Since you already have a Firebase reference handy, it is perfectly acceptable to simply use the vanilla Firebase client library API methods.

Answer (score 1):

try `".write"` instead of `"write"`

I recommend you modify this example to ensure no overwrites:

```
// we can write as long as old data or new data does not exist
// in other words, if this is a delete or a create, but not an update
".write": "!data.exists() || !newData.exists()"
```